# add new array into an array from its array's subarray

Tags: javascript

I have an array,

```
let arr =[{SLNO:1, modules:[{id:1, name:DTR},{id:5, name:DYR},{id:8, name:YUR}]},
          {SLNO:2, modules:[{id:6, name:DTTR},{id:9, name:TTDYR}]}]
```

I want to add a new array into this array with modules IDs like,

```
let newarr =[{SLNO:1, modules:[{id:1, name:DTR},{id:5, name:DYR},{id:8, name:YUR}], mIDS:[1,5,8]},
          {SLNO:2, modules:[{id:6, name:DTTR},{id:9, name:TTDYR}],  mIDS:[6,9]}]
```

How to write like this?

Comment: update tag to javascript and array and show your work what you have tried so far ?

Comment: `const newArr = arr.map(({modules, ...rest}) => ({...rest, modules, mIDS: [...modules.map(({ id }) => id)]}));` <--- Please try this and share feedback, if any.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `forEach` [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) and the `map` [(documentation)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) methods

```js
const arr = [{
    SLNO: 1,
    modules: [
       {id: 1,name: "DTR"},
       {id: 5, name: "DYR"},
       {id: 8,name: "YUR"}
    ]
  },
  {
    SLNO: 2,
    modules: [
       {id: 6,name: "DTTR"},
       {id: 9,name: "TTDYR"}
    ]
  }
]

arr.forEach(item => {
  const ids = item.modules.map(x => x.id)
  item.mIDS = ids
})

console.log(arr)
```

You can also do it using the [Array#Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function. It has the benefits to **not** modify the existing array and generate a new one.

```js
const arr = [{
    SLNO: 1,
    modules: [
       {id: 1,name: "DTR"},
       {id: 5, name: "DYR"},
       {id: 8,name: "YUR"}
    ]
  },
  {
    SLNO: 2,
    modules: [
       {id: 6,name: "DTTR"},
       {id: 9,name: "TTDYR"}
    ]
  }
]

const newArr = arr.map(item => ({...item, mIDS: item.modules.map(x => x.id)}))

console.log(newArr)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using map

```js
let arr = [{
    SLNO: 1,
    modules: [{
      id: 1,
      name: 'DTR'
    }, {
      id: 5,
      name: 'DYR'
    }, {
      id: 8,
      name: 'YUR'
    }]
  },
  {
    SLNO: 2,
    modules: [{
      id: 6,
      name: 'DTTR'
    }, {
      id: 9,
      name: 'TTDYR'
    }]
  }
]
arr.map((item) => {
  item.mIDS = item.modules.map((item) => item.id)
  return item
})
console.log(arr)
```